# Cases without repetition

Tags: pattern-matching

What would be the fastest way to find all cases in a list that match a pattern but without repetition in the result?

`Cases[ list, pattern ] // DeleteDuplicates`
does the job but is not so efficient since it adds all duplicates to a list and only then deletes them (while not adding them would be faster).
`Cases[ DeleteDuplicates @ list, pattern ]` will first delete all duplicates from the list while only the duplicates from the result need to be deleted.

I searched through the documentation of `Cases` but could not find any way to turn off repetition.

**Edit: A Toy Example**

One of the cases I have to deal with is the following. I have a large (>10^6) list of equations in some variables, say `{ x[1], ..., x[n] }`, and say for example that I would like to use all equalities of the form `( n_?NumericQ == x[i_] | x[i_] == n_?NumericQ ) /; i >= m`  to find out some information about the variables `x[i]` with `i > m`. This could be useful to see whether there's some inconsistency, or maybe some of these values are too big, or not real, etc.

One way to tackle this problem is as follows

```
(* Small toy example *)

equationList = 
  {
    x[1] == x[3]+x[5],
    2 == x[3] x[4],
    6 == x[1] x[4],
    3 == x[1],
    x[5]^2 == x[2]x[3],
    x[1] == x[3] + x[5],
    3 == x[1],
    7 == x[6]
  };

infoVars[ m_Integer, list_List ] := 
  Cases[ 
    list, 
    ( n_?NumericQ == x[i_] | x[i_] == n_?NumericQ ) /; i >= m :> x[i] -> n
  ];
```

`infoVars[ 1 , equationList ]` then returns `{ x[1] -> 3, x[1] -> 3, x[6] -> 7 }`, i.e. a list with duplicate elements.

I could of course apply DeleteDuplicates to this list, but if `equationList` contains a lot of duplicate matching expressions, then Mathematica would basically create a long list with multiple duplicates. This is a bit stupid since I have to delete these duplicates anyway so it would be nice if there were an option such that `Cases` would not add all those duplicates to the list in the first place.

Deleting duplicates beforehand might also be costly because I would delete duplicates in which I might not be interested.

Comment: Could you please load some concrete test cases along with expected outcome?

Comment: **will first delete all duplicates from the list while only the duplicates from the result need to be deleted** I do not see what is the difference?  But it will help to give specific test case where you think it makes difference.

Comment: Btw, I think the question is not clear. Since Cases uses a PATTERN, not an actual expression to search for, what do you mean by it finds all duplicates? It just finds all expressions that match the PATTERN. If you just want the first case only found, then there is a specific function for that, called `FirstCase` see help **gives the first Subscript[e, i] to match pattern**

Comment: @Syed: I added an example that hopefully clarifies my question.

Comment: @Nasser: for the first comment: The outcome is the same, the efficiency is not. Looping over a list to add all cases of interest to a second list, and then deleting duplicates is (I think) slower than looping over a list and adding cases of interest to a second list, except if they are already in the second list. In the first case 2 new lists are created, in the second case only 1 new list.
For the second comment: I hope the example clarifies why FirstCase doesn't do what I want. If not I'll gladly give more explanation

Comment: **infoVars[ 1 , equationList ] then returns { x[1] -> 3, x[1] -> 3, x[6] -> 7 }** That is not what I get   screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cg8pL.png)

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally put > instead of >= (or equivalently, used infoVars[ 1, ... ] instead of infoVars[ 0, ... ]). Fixed it in last edit

Comment: Why not `infoVars[1, Union[equationList]]` ? Is the order of the equations important?

Comment: @Syed  This was suggested. OP does not want to remove duplicate before or after calling Cases as they say it is no efficient.

Answer (score 4):

As someone said, premature optimization is the root of all evil.

I think you are trying to optimize something not needed. As mentioned in comments, you can simply remove duplicate items from the list either before or after calling Cases.  `DeleteDuplicates` or `Union` are very much optimized and fast as they are built in functions.

But if you must do it inside cases, here is one option.

```
 lis = {Sin[x], Sin[2 x], Cos[x], x, Sin[x]}
 Cases[lis, Sin[_]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We see duplicates. Change Cases to check as it finds pattern, if such an expression was already collected or not. It does this by keeping in a side list all expressions found so far. If the current one was not found so far, it will add it to the side list and use it, else it will skip it.

```
lis = {Sin[x], Sin[2 x], Cos[x], x, Sin[x]}
c = {};
Cases[lis, x_ /; MatchQ[x, Sin[_]] :> If[FreeQ[c, x], AppendTo[c, x]; x, Nothing]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

No duplicates.

Is this more efficient that simply removing duplicates before or after? I doubt it. But Cases needs a way to know if it has found such an expression or not as it traverse the list. How would it "remember" that other than keeping a list of what was detected by the pattern?

Any way, Cases has no such option and I think for a good reason.

My 2 cents advice, forget about this goal, and simply remove duplicates either before calling Cases or after. i.e. simply do

```
lis = {Sin[x], Sin[2 x], Cos[x], x, Sin[x]}
Cases[lis, Sin[_]] // Union
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

I agree with everything that [Nasser](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/70/nasser) has said [above](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/280732/106).

However, if you don't mind the result as an association (rather than a list of rules), you *could* do something like the following?  Not sure how efficient this is compared with using `DeleteDuplicates`, though.

```
infoVarsZ[ m_Integer, list_List ] := Module[{assoc = <||>},
 Cases[list, 
   ( n_?NumericQ == x[i_] | x[i_] == n_?NumericQ ) /; i >= m :> AssociateTo[assoc,x[i] -> n]
      ];
 assoc]

infoVarsZ[1 , equationList]
(* <|x[1] -> 3, x[6] -> 7|> *)
```